# Condition Spread based on Object props

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, spread

I'm looking for way to remove empty or null props, on my example obj2, I want to avoid copying the birthPlace property or any other prop that comes empty.

```
const obj1 = { firstName: 'Foo', age: 22 };

const obj2 = { lastName: 'Bar', gender: 'M', birthPlace: '' };

const newObj = { ...obj1, ...obj2 };
```

Desired result:

```
{firstName: 'Foo', age: 22, lastName: 'Bar', gender: 'M'}
```

Is it possible using Conditional Objects props using Spread Operators in javascript?

```
const updateUserObj = {
  ...(obj1 !== check here<hasPropEmpty> && obj2)
}
```

Comment: I don't think there's any shorthand notation for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`Object#entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) you get the key-value pairs of an object, then, using [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) you iterate over these pairs to filter out the ones with empty values. Then, using [`Object#fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) you construct back the resulting pairs to an object.

```js
const filterProps = (obj = {}) => 
  Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(obj).filter(([key, value]) => 
      value !== null && value !== undefined && value !== ''
    )
  );

const obj1 = { firstName: 'Foo', age: 22 };
const obj2 = { lastName: 'Bar', gender: 'M', birthPlace: '' };

const newObj = { ...filterProps(obj1), ...filterProps(obj2) };

console.log(newObj);
```

Answer (score 2):

There's no shorthand for it, but you can easily write a function that filters out those properties.

```js
function nonEmptyProps(obj) {
  return Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj).filter(([k, v]) => v !== null && v !== ''));
}

const obj1 = { firstName: 'Foo', age: 22 };

const obj2 = { lastName: 'Bar', gender: 'M', birthPlace: '' };

const newObj = {...nonEmptyProps(obj1), ...nonEmptyProps(obj2)};
console.log(newObj);
```